# Is there a way to use Foursquare's API to search including category ID and price parameter?

Tags: swift, api, foursquare

I'm trying to use the Foursquare API to search, but specify both category ID's and a price. Using the request [`GET https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/explore`](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/api/venues/explore) I can specify a price but not category ID's, however I can enter a query - which makes me wonder, what exactly does the query parameter do?

If I use the request [`GET https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search`](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/api/venues/search) I can specify category IDs, however I can't specify a price parameter.

Finally, I'm using Swift with the pods FoursquareAPI & SwiftyJSON so my relevant code looks something like this:

```
func getObject(limit: Int, category: String){
    let client = FoursquareAPIClient(clientId: "JMBLK0SDZ0N2NF5TG3UCLMOF4FA5FKA14AIOZ4P4TS4MHEWO", clientSecret: "<my client secret>")

    let parameter: [String: String] = [
        "near": destination!,
        "limit": "1",
        "query": category!,
        "price": String(describing: budget!),
        ];

    client.request(path: "venues/explore", parameter: parameter) { result in

        switch result {
        case let .success(data):
            print("Success")
            guard let json = try? JSON(data: data) else{
                print("\(#function): Unable to retrieve json object")
                return
            }
            if json["meta"]["code"] == 200{
                self.parse(jsonObject: json)
            }
        case let .failure(error):
            // Error handling
            switch error {
            case let .connectionError(connectionError):
                print(connectionError)
            case let .responseParseError(responseParseError):
                print(responseParseError)   // e.g. JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.
            case let .apiError(apiError):
                print(apiError.errorType)   // e.g. endpoint_error
                print(apiError.errorDetail) // e.g. The requested path does not exist.
            }
        }//end switch
    }//end client.request
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To anyone reading this thread, I've found a better solution than Brett's:

The [/search/recommendations](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/api/venues/recommendations) endpoint. I guess it's new so it's not listed with the other API docs, but it allows the specification of `categories`, `price`, as well as `localTime` and `localDay` which allow you to specify venues that are open at a specific time.

There are many other cool parameters, such as `features` which I believe are exclusive to this endpoint, and it's worthwhile to check out.

Comment: Nice! How'd you find this?

Comment: Through an email correspondence with someone from Foursquare. Apparently they're still working on it.

Comment: Hi, sorry for bringing this up, what is the right way to specify localTime parameter in request? I'm writing localTime = 15 but it gives me error

Answer (score 2):

It appears there are two options:

1. Use `/explore` endpoint, with the `price`, and `section` params, where `section` is one of - `food`, `drinks`, `coffee`, `shops`, `arts`, `outdoors`, `sights`, etc
2. Use `/explore` endpoint, with the `price` and `query` params, where `query` is a string matching the [Foursquare category name](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/resources/categories)

In my limited tests, this 2nd option produced decent results. For example, a GET request to:

```
api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/explore?near=SOME,%20LOCATION&price=3&query=Deli%20/%20Bodega

// client_id, client_secret, and v params will all be needed as well
```

returns venues in the `3` price range, and only venues in the "Deli / Bodega" category.

Similar searches for the "Coffee Shop" category produced relevant results.

Comment: This'll have to do then. Just seems strange that they opted to exclude the category parameter for the /explore endpoint. Especially since you cannot enter multiple queries separated by commas the same way you can categories in the /search endpoint.

Comment: Yes, there are many things that don't make sense in the Foursquare API unfortunately.